# how to make text boxes keep the same sum

Tags: c#, winforms, math, textbox

I am making an application that has 2 textboxes that stores numbers, but the catch is the numbers they store add up to a fixed sum. I am trying to use the textchanged event handler in order to do this, so as I type, the other textbox updates with the correct number that adds to the sum of the textbox I am currently typing in. The code I have so far is

```
private void txtMikeWater_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double num;
    bool parse = Double.TryParse(txtMikeWater.Text, out num);
    if (parse && num >= 0 && num <= expenses[2])
        txtPattiWater.Text = (expenses[2] - num).ToString();

}

private void txtPattiWater_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double num;
    bool parse = Double.TryParse(txtPattiWater.Text, out num);
    if (parse && num >= 0 && num <= expenses[2])
        txtMikeWater.Text = (expenses[2] - num).ToString();

}
```

it works at first, but I also have a textbox that calculates rent and I'm hoping it will add or subtract depending on the difference between these two textboxes. So for instance, if rent is split 2 ways at a 1000$ (so 500$ each) if one person pays say an extra 50$ on a different bill, it subtracts the rent cost from one person but then adds it on. So then rent would cost 550 for one person and 450 for the other. I can't figure out a way to do this without screwing up the text within the textboxes. Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

EDIT: the expenses array contains the max values for that particular bill. I have it setup so it initially divides the bill in half

EDIT: adding a couple gifs if I can to try and give some perspective

[image]

This is kinda of what I am trying to do, and it works fine at first, but I want it to take the 100$ that is being taken away from "Patti" and added to the amount of rent she has to pay whereas "Mike's" rent would get subtracted since he had to pay an extra 100$ on the utility.
But then I also run into this problem:
[image]

once I click to a different item (it's supposed to load the values for that item) it screws up the textboxes. I think it has to do with the fact that the textchanged handler is still being called when I switch selecteditems.

Comment: very confusing, at first sight....include steps screenshot to understand better so that we try to help

Comment: @Piyush just added some gifs and more of an explanation for some more clarification :)

Comment: be careful of an endless loop when your TextChanged events are changing other control's text!

Comment: I know but the problem is they both have to have the method in each text box otherwise only one will change the other Q_Q

Comment: that is my main problem right now. I can't figure out how to make them both change each other without it causing problems

Comment: Also, if one person pays more on one bill, I thought the goal was to subtract that amount from the other person's portion of THE SAME BILL, not the rent? That part of your problem I don't understand. If you want to update a person's total expenses (not just the rent), then it makes sense (and you should re-word it).

Comment: @RufusL sorry haha I'm pretty bad at wording things the way I want :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way you could accomplish this. It might seem like overkill, but it might make it easier in the long run if you start adding more tennants, expenses, or controls that need updating.

To start with, create a simple class that stores Expenses:

```
public class Expenses
{
    public double Rent { get; set; }
    public double Internet { get; set; }
    public double Groceries { get; set; }
    public double Water { get; set; }
    public double Electricity { get; set; }
    public double TV { get; set; }

    public double Total
    {
        get { return Rent + Internet + Groceries + Water + Electricity + TV; }
    }
}
```

You could create an instance of this class to represent the total household expenses, and also one for each tenant:

```
private Expenses totalExpenses = new Expenses
{
    Electricity = 100,
    Groceries = 300,
    Internet = 65,
    Rent = 1300,
    TV = 45,
    Water = 20
};

private Expenses pattiExpenses;
private Expenses mikeExpenses;
```

Then, when your app starts (assuming you're not loading data from some other datasource), you can set each person's expense to an equal share of the household expenses:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    int tenantCount = 2;

    // Start each person out splitting the total expenses
    pattiExpenses = new Expenses
    {
        Electricity = totalExpenses.Electricity / tenantCount,
        Groceries = totalExpenses.Groceries / tenantCount,
        Internet = totalExpenses.Internet / tenantCount,
        Rent = totalExpenses.Rent / tenantCount,
        TV = totalExpenses.TV / tenantCount,
        Water = totalExpenses.Water / tenantCount
    };

    mikeExpenses = new Expenses
    {
        Electricity = totalExpenses.Electricity / tenantCount,
        Groceries = totalExpenses.Groceries / tenantCount,
        Internet = totalExpenses.Internet / tenantCount,
        Rent = totalExpenses.Rent / tenantCount,
        TV = totalExpenses.TV / tenantCount,
        Water = totalExpenses.Water / tenantCount
    };

    UpdateTextBoxes();
}
```

Next, instead of adding and removing event handlers for the textboxes, you could have a global variable that tracks whether or not the text is being updated from code:

```
private bool textUpdatingFromCode = false;
```

And you can create a method that sets this variable to true, updates all the textboxes, and then sets the variable to false again:

```
private void UpdateTextBoxes()
{
    textUpdatingFromCode = true;

    txtPattiWater.Text = pattiExpenses.Water.ToString();
    txtMikeWater.Text = mikeExpenses.Water.ToString();

    // . . .
    // Continue for any other text boxes, including 
    // one that displays each person's total

    txtPattiTotal.Text = pattiExpenses.Total.ToString();
    txtMikeTotal.Text = mikeExpenses.Total.ToString();

    textUpdatingFromCode = false;
}
```

And finally, in your `TextChanged` events, you can have code that just updates the objects and then refreshes all the text boxes. This will allow you to update multiple textboxes from any `TextChanged` event:

```
private void txtMikeWater_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!textUpdatingFromCode)
    {
        double amount;
        if (double.TryParse(txtMikeWater.Text, out amount))
        {
            mikeExpenses.Water = amount;
            pattiExpenses.Water = totalExpenses.Water - mikeExpenses.Water;
            UpdateTextBoxes();
        }
    }
}

private void txtPattiWater_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!textUpdatingFromCode)
    {
        double amount;
        if (double.TryParse(txtMikeWater.Text, out amount))
        {
            pattiExpenses.Water = amount;
            mikeExpenses.Water = totalExpenses.Water - pattiExpenses.Water;
            UpdateTextBoxes();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly where I was going to suggest with your "textUpdatingFromCode" check... if done as a passthru result from another, just get out and ignore changing again.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the text of one TextBox from another in the TextChanged event if you temporarily unassign the TextChanged event from the one you're modifying, modify it, then re-assign it again:

```
private void txtMikeWater_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int amount;
    if (int.TryParse(txtMikeWater.Text, out amount))
    {
        txtPattiWater.TextChanged -= txtPattiWater_TextChanged;
        txtPattiWater.Text = (water - amount).ToString();
        txtPattiWater.TextChanged += txtPattiWater_TextChanged;
    }
}

private void txtPattiWater_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int amount;
    if (int.TryParse(txtMikeWater.Text, out amount))
    {
        txtMikeWater.TextChanged -= txtMikeWater_TextChanged;
        txtMikeWater.Text = (water - amount).ToString();
        txtMikeWater.TextChanged += txtMikeWater_TextChanged;

    }
}
```

But this is going to get ugly pretty quickly. You might consider creating a class or two to represent the expenses, then instantiate one for each tenant.

Comment: I think I managed to actually get it to work by putting the body's in an if statement of it only executing if it has focus.